# Can't detect my bluetooth mouse/keyboard in my second macbook

Tags: bluetooth, macbook, macbook-pro

I have two macbook laptops (personal and work)

- I can detect Bluetooth mouse & keyboard in my personal macbook. (M2)
- I can't detect them in my work laptop. (OS: Ventura, Intel)
- When I open my second Macbook, I turn my first Macbook into sleep mode.

Are they stuck to my first laptop somehow?

Comment: Are they both signed into the same iCloud account? If so, then you can use Universal Control & just drag the mouse from one screen to the next. Otherwise you have to connect physically to enable initial BT connection to the other Mac.

Comment: How can I connect physically? Mouse has no cable

Comment: How do you charge it? Or… if it's not an Apple mouse, what is it & how did you initiate pairing in the first place?

Comment: Samsung. Battery, sadly. But I will try other option.